# Is there a standard notation for the measure $E \mapsto \mu(E \cap S)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, notation

If $\mu$ is a measure and $S$ is $\mu$-measurable, it is easy to see that the measure $E \mapsto \mu(E \cap S)$ defines a measure on the $\sigma$-algebra where $\mu$ is defined. I have been using the notation $\mu_S$ to denote this measure. However, I would like to use a standard notation, if there is one available.

Comment: I believe $\mu_{\llcorner S}$ is at least somewhat standard.

Comment: IMO, $\mu_S$ is a completely valid option as long as you explain it in your text.